# Can not send data to mysql server using php

Tags: android

I want to send data to mysql server through php. My app is working perfectly fine but the data are not shown in the database.here is my code:

```
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1:4001/file.php");


            List<NameValuePair> pair=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            pair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fn",fname));
            pair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ln",lname));


            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pair));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

and my php:

```
            <?php

            $con=mysql_connect("host","username");
            if(!$con)
            {
            die("Could Not Connect".mysql_error());
            }

            $db="CREATE DATABASE login";
            mysql_query($db,$con);

            mysql_select_db("login",$con);

            $tab="CREATE TABLE info(FirstName varchar(20),LastName varchar(20))";
            mysql_query($tab,$con);

            $user_fname=$_POST['fn'];
            $user_lname=$_POST['ln'];

            $row="INSERT INTO info (FirstName,LastName) 
            VALUES ($user_fname,$user_lname)";
            mysql_query($row,$con);

            mysql_close($con);

            ?>
```

Preferable way , Not using JSON.
Your Help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend creating the database and table every time. Also, have you tried posting some values to the script manually so that you can test its output? Perhaps it is having an error. Furthermore, `mysql_query` is old and deprecated, you should use the new mysql libraries in PHP. Furthermore your code is easily SQL injectable - you ened to sanitize the input values before using them in a query.

Comment: I have tested my php file and its working correctly . Basically what i need to just access the php file from my app ... !!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with

```
$row="INSERT INTO info (FirstName,LastName) 
        VALUES ($user_fname,$user_lname)";
```

Change it to

```
$row= mysql_query("INSERT INTO info (FirstName,LastName)  VALUES('$user_fname', '$user_lname')");
if ($row) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";
    echo $row;
}
```

Comment: Basically I have an Exception at the line given below :

Comment: HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);